# spring rabbitmq - consume multiple messages at the same time

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm using **RabbitMQ** in my spring boot application in this way:

**Sender:**

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("exchange", "routingKey", "Message Text");
```

**Listener:**

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "queueName")
public void receive(String message) {
    System.out.println("start");  
    //send an http request that takes for example 4 seconds 
    System.out.println("end");  
}
```

With above codes, when application executes sender part, `receive` method invoked. My problem is **while `receive` method is processing a message, if sender part put another message into queue, the method does not proccess new message** and so second `start` word wont be printed until `end` word of previous message. In the other words, **I want to know, how a message listener can proccess multiple messages at a time** I don't know what is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

From the problem you are stating, it looks like your listener is configured for single thread. Refer to the container listener configuration docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#containerAttributes)  and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#listener-concurrency) especially the concurrency settings. The concurrency settings control how many threads process messages on the queue at same time.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I found `setConcurrentConsumers()` method. But that method creates static numbers of threads. Is there any way for doing it dynamically? I means, spring handles it and add a thread **on demand**.

Comment: @hamed You should look to handle it statically. By default, your JVM only spins up so many available threads. When you enter the realm of concurrency, you start to have to be cognizant of these JVM-related components.

Comment: You can provide "maxConcurrentConsumers" to provide upper bound and the listener container dynamically adjusts the number of threads depending on load. Also you have options to provide your own executor. The docs explains very well the algorithm for increasing / decreasing consumer dynamically. However you have to keep in mind the processing power available to consumers and the kind of work the consumers are doing - CPU bound or IO bound. Generally if your workload is IO bound you can provide more threads than number of CPUs. Unbounded consumer number is anyway not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot, just add this configuration to the application properties:

```
# Minimum number of listener invoker threads
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.concurrency=5
```

And your listener will start accepting messages in parallel (multiple threads). There are other configurations that you can check too. Like the max number of listener invoker threads (check spring boot doc for more info).